# Excluding or selectively including subproperties when serializing a complex class in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for an efficient way to selectively serialize certain subproperties of a complex class.

For example, below is the output of the specified command

> Get-Date | Select -Property Ticks, TimeOfDay | ConvertTo-Json

```
{
    "Ticks":  637590063235806354,
    "TimeOfDay":  {
                      "Ticks":  399235806354,
                      "Days":  0,
                      "Hours":  11,
                      "Milliseconds":  580,
                      "Minutes":  5,
                      "Seconds":  23,
                      "TotalDays":  0.46207847957638887,
                      "TotalHours":  11.089883509833333,
                      "TotalMilliseconds":  39923580.635400005,
                      "TotalMinutes":  665.39301059,
                      "TotalSeconds":  39923.5806354
                  }
}
```

I want my serialized class to look like this:

```
{
    "Ticks":  637590063235806354,
    "TimeOfDay":  {
                      "TotalMinutes":  665.39301059,
                      "TotalSeconds":  39923.5806354
                  }
}
```

Rebuilding the class with the required properties is not the desired solution as for the real usecase, the class is more complex and contains many more levels.

The following does not work, but might give a better sense for what I'm looking for.

> Get-Date | Select -Property Ticks, TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes,
> TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds | ConvertTo-Json

Answer (score 0):

You can do this kind of thing:

```
Get-Date | Select-Object Ticks, @{N="TimeofDay";e={[pscustomobject]@{TotalMinutes=$_.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes;TotalSeconds=$_.TimeofDay.TotalSeconds}}} | ConvertTo-Json
```